# java.lang.NullPointerException in Eclipse when trying to open GraphicLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I can't see `GraphicLayout`. The project runs correctly. But recently there is not design of layout when i click on `GraphicLayout`. The below message will be show. It did not like this before and every thing was ok.

```
  activity_main.xml: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Of course app execute correctly.

[image]

activity_main.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:background="@color/ranglayout"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

  <View
    android:id="@+id/view_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/rangTitleBar" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_exit"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_exit" />

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_exit"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_exit"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:text="conversion  "
    android:textColor="@color/rangTextbox"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

  <View
    android:id="@+id/view_top"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/viewwidth"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/viewheight"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view_title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"


   />

   <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_first"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/spinnerwidth"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/spinnerheight"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view_top"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view_top"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1" 
    android:entries="@array/array_spinner"
    />

   <View
    android:id="@+id/view_second"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/viewwidth"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/viewheightbetween"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view_top"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view_top"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
     />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_number"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/edittxtwidth"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/edittxtheight"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner_first"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/spinner_first"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="phone" 
    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize">

  </EditText>

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_flesh"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/fleshwidth"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/fleshheight"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner_first"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view_top"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_red256" 
     android:gravity="right"
    />

   <View
    android:id="@+id/view_third"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/viewwidth"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/viewheight"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view_second"
      android:layout_below="@+id/view_second"

    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
   />

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt_result"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/edittxtwidth"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/edittxtheight"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edt_number"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/view_third"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_flesh"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="phone"
     android:textSize="@dimen/textsize" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_second"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/spinnerwidth"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/spinnerheight"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view_third"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/view_third"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:entries="@array/array_spinner" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/below"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/viewwidth"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/viewheightbelow"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view_top"
    android:layout_below="@id/view_third"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/flipper1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/flipperheight"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/below"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/below"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/below"

    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/ImgWidth"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/Imgheight"
        android:src="@drawable/img1"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/ImgWidth"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/Imgheight"
        android:src="@drawable/img2"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/ImgWidth"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/Imgheight"
        android:src="@drawable/img3"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/ImgWidth"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/Imgheight"
        android:src="@drawable/img4"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/ImgWidth"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/Imgheight"
        android:src="@drawable/img5"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />



  </ViewFlipper>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_marquee"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/below"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/below"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/below"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:ellipsize="marquee"
     android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:lines="1"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
     android:text="hello"
    android:textColor="#ff4500"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize" />

     </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: There are few strange errors in eclipse sometimes. Recently I've faced one. Try to clean and rebuild your project. If still problem not solved. Delete eclipse and install it again.

Comment: Can you show some screenshot ?

Comment: Post your layout code also .

Answer (score 3):

I had also same problem & It's Solution is :

go to App Theme in Graphical Layout of Eclipse and set it as Theme via All sub option of App Theme or Change it as any suitable Theme for current xml file.

Please Check the Following setting in graphical layout as : App Theme --> All --> Theme.

Best Of Luck..!

Answer (score 0):

Choose appropriate theme under the 'App Theme' menu as per the min SDK. This would solve your problem.